# truncate not defined in DrRacket

Tags: scheme, racket, truncate, integer-division

I am trying to use the `truncate` function in scheme and DrRacket keeps issuing this message

```
ProblemA.rkt:27:46: truncate: this function is not defined in: truncate
```

Is there an import or something I can add so the compiler can find the library for `truncate`?

Basically I want to do integer division in scheme so `98/10 = 9` instead of `9.8` but the `truncate` function isn't working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(quotient 98 10)` does what you want.

i am actually a big fan of the "division returns float" behavior. the integers are not closed under division (in theory). and `1/2 == 0` can introduce subtle bugs (in practice). i always "from __future__ import division" in python too.

Comment: No Problem should be all set :)